# How to change "Save Draft" value on Webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I want to change the button text value from "Save Draft" to "Save". How can I target the button (CSS or custom module works for me)? I used to target forms like this:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Ask question';
```

As there are multiple submit buttons, I don't know how to target the one with the class "webform-draft form-submit".

```
function customisations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_88') {

  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to change the text for Save Draft button is:

```
function customisations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_88') {
    $form['actions']['draft']['#value'] = 'Save';
  }
}
```

This would change only for **Save to Draft** button. In order to change the submit button text of the webform, we can use the configuration of the Webform to change it. URL for the same is **node/88/webform/configure**.

[image]

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I changed the submit button already. just needed the draft button. perfect! many thanks